# How to save file with custom file extension in java?

Tags: java

Dear brothers Hope you all right?
I'm designing a document program, however, rather to save file .text extension or using any other MS-Office API in java, i want to create my custom file format such as ".sad" extension so that this sort of file can only be read by my programs, how this can be possible?

Comment: Creating a new "standard" is not the solution these days. It makes it hard to make your documents work with other software. Which is a bad idea, because no one will use software which you get locked into.

Comment: my file can be open with my program, not with other as MS-Word can't be opened with other programs. does it need to create any encoding scheme to read and write my file.

Comment: "so that this soft of file can only be read by my programs." sounds like a custom encoding scheme to me

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement seems ambiguous. Are you looking to make a program that creates MS Office Word documents or plain text files with a custom file extension?

In the case of the former, you can't have a custom extension as MS Word documents, by definition, have a .doc / .docx extension.

However, if you are looking to create a program that produces text files then you can easily have a custom extension. Just look at this tutorial: [How to create a file in Java](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-create-a-file-in-java/)

Answer (score 0):

I already stated why this is a bad idea. Yet I have a solution for you (more like a how-not-to-do-it)

Take your plain text you want to save, convert it to bytes and apply this "highly enthusiastic encryption nobody will ever be able to break" on it:

```
string plainText = "yadayada";
bytes[] bytesFromText = toBytes(plainText);
bytes[] encrypted = new Array(sizeof(bytesFromText)*2);
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(bytesFromText); i++){
    if((i modulo 2) == 0){
        encrypted.push(toByte(Math.random modulo 255));
    }
    encrypted.push(bytesFromText[i]);
}
```

I let it up to you to figure out why this is a bad idea and how to decrypt it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can create file with any extension

For example,

```
File f = new File("confidential.sad");
```

Hope this will work for you :)

Answer (score 0):

## Working with custom files in Java

Here is the tutorial that will help you in getting the concept about how to create your own files with custom extension such as .doc or .sad with some information embedded in it and after saving the file you want to read that information form the file.

> ## ZIP
>
> Similar applications often use archives to store data. Consider MS-Word and its documents >with the .docx file extension. If you change the extension of any .docx file to .zip, you >will find that the document is actually a zip archive, with only a different extension.

https://www.ict.social/java/files/working-with-custom-files-in-java-zip-archive

Answer (score 0):

I have published a library that saves files, and handles everything with one line of code only, you can find it here along with its documentation

[Github repository](https://github.com/rasmi-aw/StorageManager)

and the answer to your question is so easy

```
String path = FileSaver
        .get()
        .save(file,"file.custom");
```